# AS3 CSS- like classes for Objects

Tags: actionscript-3, rollover, css

I'm very new to AS3.

I'd like to give certain objects in a MC the "class" ( meaning css like class ) rollover. So I can automatically create a rollOver that fades up all objects declared as rollOver objects.

jQuery exmaple

```
$("#myObject .rollOverObject").animate(...);
```

What would be the best way to achieve something like that in AS3?

Thank you in advance and best regards.

Comment: i think it may be time to learn a *new* paradigm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as CSS classes in AS3. What you can do, however, is create an `EventListener` on the MC's and do your animations within there. It'll look like this.

```
for (var i : int = 0; i < mcContainer.numChildren; i++) 
{
    // reference to a child of the container
    var mcChild:MovieClip = mcContainer.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;

    // validate by name
    if(mcChild.name == "something you want to check")
    {
        mcChild.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onMcRollOver);
    }
}

function onMcRollOver(event:MouseEvent) : void
{
    // create a reference to the MovieClip that is rolled over
    var mcTarget:MovieClip = event.currentTarget as MovieClip;

    // do what you like with the mcTarget
    mcTarget.alpha = 0.5;
}
```

If you're done using the `MovieClips`, or don't need the `ROLL_OVER` listeners anymore you can remove these listeners in a simular way.

```
for (var i : int = 0; i < mcContainer.numChildren; i++) 
{
    // reference to a child of the container
    var mcChild:MovieClip = mcContainer.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;

    // validate by name
    if(mcChild.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER))
    {
        mcChild.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onMcRollOver);
    }
}
```

A quick [Google search](http://www.google.nl/search?aq=0&oq=as3%20eventlistene&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=as3%20event%20listeners) can help you further with your learning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I need to dynamically access several objects without knowing how much there are. There might be a way to do this by getting a list of every MC and checking the names. That way I could name the rollOver objects rO_ExampleName or something like that. Is there something like myMovieClip.each()???

Comment: I updated my answer. You can loop through the children using `numChildren`

Comment: Thank you very much. I just have one last question a little off topic. If I load a movie with the loader class I can access it using myLoader.content. Unfortunately myLoader.content is a DisplayObject and not a MovieClip so I get an error if I use the loop you suggested. Is there a workaround or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should typecast your `myLoader.content` like so: `MovieClip(myLoader.content)`. So Flash knows how to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun; Take a look at eaze tween: http://code.google.com/p/eaze-tween/